# SQL Server get rows from table and display in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner with SQL and have a question. I have a table with user data like this

```
uid  nid val   
+---+---+---+
| 1 | x | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | x | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | x | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | y | 4 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | y | 4 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | y | 4 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | z | 5 |
+---+---+---+
```

Where uid is a user ID, nid is a Name id which is used to identify a value and val is the actual value.

I want to write a query which gives the following result

```
uid   x   y   z
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Are there functions or statements that can read data from multiple rows and put it in columns ?

Comment: Read about `PIVOT` or *conditional aggregation*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is stored in a struct called entity-attribute value (EAV).  One way of "flattening" it is to use `group by` or `pivot`:

```
select uid,
       max(case when nid = 'x' then val end) as x,
       max(case when nid = 'y' then val end) as y,
       max(case when nid = 'z' then val end) as z
from t
group by uid;
```

If you don't know the specific values you want in the result table, then you need dynamic SQL.  The query is quite a bit more challenging.  I would suggest that you start by Googling "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: Will this work if the val are different for different uid ?

Comment: @Nithin . . . Yes.  It will return `NULL` for the ids that don't have a value.

Answer (score 1):

We Can Achieve Desired result using Dynamic Sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOt NUll
Drop Table #Temp
;With cte(uid,  nid, val)
AS
(
SELECT 1 , 'x', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'x', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 'x', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , 'y', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'y', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 'y', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , 'z', 5 
)
SELECT * INTO #Temp FRom cte

DECLARE @dynamicCol nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @dynamicCol2 nvarchar(max)

SELECT @dynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 'ISNULL('+nid+',''0'') AS '+QUOTENAME(nid)   FROM  #Temp
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @dynamicCol2=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + QUOTENAME(nid)   FROM  #Temp
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql='
            SELECT [uid] , '+ @dynamicCol +' From
            (
            SELECT * From
            #temp
            )AS Src
            PIVOT 
            (
            MAX([val]) For [nid ] IN ('+@dynamicCol2+')
            )
            AS Pvt
            '

PRINT @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

OutPut

```
uid x   y   z
--------------
1   3   4   5
2   3   4   0
3   3   4   0
```